# Set a weight to each item in a list

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, recursion, functional-programming

I have got a comma-separated list of fruits, and they are listed in order from most-relevant to least-relevant.

e.g:

```
"fruits":"apple, orange, lemon, apple, strawberry, pineapple, banana"
```

I need to assign weights to each element in the list based on the listed order and the amount of times each item is repeated.

The sum of weights must be = 100 (%)

But I can not conceive a mathematical function to achieve a solution:

What is a good general algorithm to implement this behaviour?

Maybe there are some options already available in C#?

Comment: Sample of what you want to get as result could help... especially what you expect for "apple" in your list (same for both, somehow different,...)?

Comment: frequency weight should be the easy part. but it's not at all clear how you intend to assign an "importance" weight ("based on the listed order") from a value's ordinal position(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to think in steps.

Let's split it into a workable list...

```
var fruitList = "apple, orange, lemon, apple, strawberry, pineapple, banana"
  .Split(", ".ToCharArray())
```

...that carries with it an index representing the order, since that's important.

```
.Select((name, index) => {
  return new {name, index + 1};
})
```

We have to stop and think about how relevant order is compared to amount of times. They have to share the allotted 100 between each other, but how? Is order really important and amount of times not that important (99/1), or vice versa (1/99), or is it 50/50?

Let's assume they split the relevance 50/50. You can lower this number to give more relevance to amount of times, or increase it to give the order more relevance.

```
var orderRelevance = .5;
var timesRelevance = 1 - orderRelevance;
```

Assuming they're all unique, the times relevance would be the allotted weight for times relevance, divided by the total number of fruits.

```
var timesWeightForOne = 100 * timesRelevance / fruitList.Count;
```

Then we'll spread out the remaining 50%. We'll assume that should be spread out linearly.

```
var orderWeightForOne = 100 * orderRelevance / fruitList.Sum(fruit => fruit.Index);
```

Now to group them while tallying the weights.

```
var weighted = fruitList
  .GroupBy(
    fruit => fruit.name,
    (name, fruits) => new {
      name,
      weight = fruits.Count() * timesWeightForOne + 
               fruits.Sum(fruit => fruit.index) * orderWeightForOne;
    }
 )
```

Let's put them in descending order by weight.

```
 .OrderByDescending(fruit => fruit.weight)
```

And make them readable.

```
 .Select(fruit => {
   var percent = Math.Round(fruit.weight, 2);
   return $"{fruit.name}: {percent}%";
 })

 Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", weighted));
```

I'm not near a compiler, so there may be errors, but that should be the gist.